# How to raise max threads for elasticsearch?

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 and I installed elasticsearch 5 on it. Now when I try to start elasticsearch using

```
/etc/init.d/elasticsearch start
```

After a few seconds in the log file I read:

```
[2016-11-19T08:47:31,442][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [shooter-1] node validation exception
bootstrap checks failed
max number of threads [1891] for user [elasticsearch] likely too low, increase to at least [2048]
```

After some googling, I came to the conclusion that I had to add the following line to `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
elasticsearch    -       nproc           2048
```

However, even after this change, I still get the same error.

I found a suggestion to uncomment the line

```
session    required   pam_limits.so
```

in `/etc/pam.d/su`, but that line was already uncommented.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally found it. The key was in this blogpost: https://fredrikaverpil.github.io/2016/04/27/systemd-and-resource-limits/

The solution was to edit the file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service` and add the line

```
LimitNPROC=2048
```

Comment: hmm.. this is already set. but im still facing the error.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this issue also and it turned out to be a systemd service override file that we likely created when originally setting up elasticsearch.

The override file is referenced here in the docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setting-system-settings.html#systemd

Check /etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service.d/ for any conf files and either remove them or update them with the correct LimitNPROC= for your elasticsearch version.

Answer (score 0):

1. When I was checking elasticsearch service on ES nodes it was throwing below error

   ```
   [root@h ~]# /etc/init.d/elasticsearch status
   ```

   elasticsearch dead but subsys locked
2. Further checked the logs and found below errors
   [2020-03-26T07:41:03,281][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [h2-es-data-0] node validation exception
   [1] bootstrap checks failed
   [1]: max number of threads [1024] for user [elasticsearch] is too low, increase to at least [2048]
   [2020-03-26T07:41:03,284][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [h2-es-data-0] stopping ...
   [2020-03-26T07:41:03,322][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [h2-es-data-0] stopped
3. I have added below lines in /etc/security/limits.conf to increase threadpool on all 6 es nodes

   `elasticsearch    -       nproc           2048`
4. Restarted services on all ES nodes

   ```
   /etc/init.d/elasticsearch restart
   ```